# Is there any simple method drawing a graph that connects 4 points in R?

Tags: r, graph

I hope to draw simple graph that connect four points:

```
x1 <- c(0,0)
x2 <- c(2,2)
x3 <- c(4,2)
x4 <- c(6,0)
```

So, I want a simple graph which starts from x1 (origion), x2, x3 and x4.

I think I can do this by defining three linear functions but I think there might be a simpler method to do this with ggplot package in R.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `polygon(c(0,2,4,6), c(0,2,2,0))` - NB base, not ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume the question is asking for a plot which starts at x1, draws a line segment to x2, then one from x2 to x3 and finally from x3 to x4.  We show classic graphics (which involves the least code) and ggplot2 below.

**1)** rbind the points together and plot:

```
m <- rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4)
plot(m, type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** or with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- as.data.frame(m)  # m defined in (1)
ggplot(d, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_line() + xlab("x") + ylab("y")
```

[image: screenshot]